# Problems with adding a module to Titanium

Tags: iphone, mobile, module, titanium, addition

I am trying to add [this module](https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar).

I have added the zip file in the titanium folder, and i have unzipped it. Now it has a folder "Module". I have taken the folder "com.ti.calendar" from that folder and I placed that one in the Titanium folder.

Now I have edited my tiapp.xml and added the following lines:

`<module version="0.1">com.ti.calendar</module>`

I added the following line in my app.js:

`var Calendar = require('com.ti.calendar');`

It always says that it can't find com.ti.calendar.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Tjeu

Comment: You need to place it in the `modules/iphone`

Comment: I did place it there, it's in the folder Library -> application support -> titanium -> modules -> iphone 

I have created a new project, and it still says it can't find that module. It seems to be looking for a .js file in my resources folder (I think when you create an application, the file should be created too? But it isn't there).

Comment: Found it, I had 2 application support folders with a titanium folder in it. Didn't know I had 2, was working with the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved.

I had 2 application support folders, one under the root and one under Users. I was working with the one under users, which was the wrong one.